# Sqitch reporting "sqitch.checkit FUNCTION does not exist" on deploy

Tags: sqitch

I'm trying to deploy a project from my dev server, where everything works fine, to a production server. I installed sqitch on the production server, did the project init, and when I try to deploy the plan, it fails with an error that "sqitch.checkit FUNCTION does not exist".

I have attempted to reinstall sqitch, but that didn't help. I've also re-initialized the project, but that also didn't change the result.

What am I missing? The docs and tutorials on the sqitch site don't have any helpful info. And, again, this all works on my devel server just fine.

Update: I'm using MySQL 5.7 on both machines, and sqitch 0.9999-2 on both machines, as well.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Are the `sqitch` versions the same on both machines? What is the database and version you are deploying against in both cases? Add information as update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.

I backed up the sqitch DB, and then deleted it from MySQL. I then recreated the sqitch DB, and started a new, junk project in a new directory. I created a deploy, and upon deploying it, sqitch re-created the sqitch.checkit function.

-- Jason